# How to use same context for multiple WARs?

Tags: spring, spring-web

I followed example in this [link](https://spring.io/blog/2007/06/11/using-a-shared-parent-application-context-in-a-multi-war-spring-application/) to use SingletonBeanFactoryLocator for using same bean in both WARs, but it seems two beans created NOT single.

I am getting below by hitting http://localhost:8080/War1/ and http://localhost:8080/War2/

Hello from SampleWeb1 using service instance com.interface21.sample.multiplecontexts.service.**SampleServiceImpl@5cfbe4c4**

Hello from SampleWeb2 using service instance com.interface21.sample.multiplecontexts.service.**SampleServiceImpl@efa0fed**

https://github.com/manojp1988/Learning/tree/JavaDSL/SingletonBeanFactoryLocatorEx

Can you please help me what I have done wrong.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, since war has individual copy of jars, same bean didnt load. Once I have skinned the wars to use same copy of spring jars, i found it working.
[Spring MVC: Sharing context within ear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162877/spring-mvc-sharing-context-within-ear)