# Load properties in different Spring context

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have two Web applications: `app-web1` and `app-web2`. `app-web2` is a module of `app-web1`. Some configurations are needed by `app-web2` that are in `app-web1`, like a `application.properties`.
I am using spring `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` to load the properties, but this just work in the context of `app-web1`. The `app-web2`'s `application-context.xml` has an import resource from other project common to both Web projects.

Below is my bean in `application-context-root.xml` that is imported by others application-context:

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location" value="classpath*:config/application.properties"/>
  <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="$spring{" />
  <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

My `application.properties` file is in `web-app1` and I want to load this properties in `app-web2` context.

How I can do this?

I am using:

- JBoss AS 7.1.1;
- Java EE 7;
- Spring 3.2.12;

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `app-web1` a *module* or a *dependency* in/of `app-web2`? Or both? Probably this file isn't in `app-web2` classpath.

Comment: @bruno, both are 2 .war files independents of each other. Concerning to maven they aren't dependencies each other. Both web projects has a dependency to a third project, the _core.jar_ in maven. The `application-context-root.xml` is in this .jar and this xml is imported as resource in `application-context.xml` of web-projects.

Comment: So `application.properties` is in `app-web1` and not in a shared project which both depends. Also, `app-web1` is packaged as `war` and isn't a `app-web2` dependency, is it? So, how this property file is in `app-web2` classpath? Also: `web-app1` and `app-web1` is the same thing, right? Maybe you should consider update your question with more detail.

Comment: @bruno,application.properties isn't in `app-web2` classpath, only in `app-web1`. What I'm looking for is a way to access the values in propertie file that are in other context. I will update my question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Relevant topic discussed here.
[SharedApplicationContext](http://spring.io/blog/2007/06/11/using-a-shared-parent-application-context-in-a-multi-war-spring-application/)

And [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394781/sharing-an-application-context-between-two-wars)

Answer (score 0):

You can use resource-copy from maven-resources-plugin.
See for more details: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <!-- here the phase you need -->
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/extra-resources</outputDirectory>
              <resources>          
                <resource>
                  <directory>src/non-packaged-resources</directory>
                  <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
              </resources>              
            </configuration>            
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already use this plugin. But isn't this what I need. The propertie are copied to artifact assembled. What I need is load the value inside the propertie file inside the .war in Jboss in runtime using spring properties.