# Jetty: Pass object from main method to servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

I have two classes `Server` (with the main method, starting the server) and `StartPageServlet` with a Servlet.

The most important part of the code is:

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // some code

        // I want to pass "anObject" to every Servlet.
        Object anObject = new Object();

        Server server = new Server(4000);
        ServletContextHandler context = 
            new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.addServlet(StartPageServlet.class, "/");
        // more code
}
```

And the StartPageServlet:

```
public class StartPageServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                      HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        // Here I want to access "anObject"
    }
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Why not just create `Object` instances in the servlets as needed? If you need global values/methods in the object you could just use the `static` key word and you wouldn't need to instantiate them at all.

Comment: Because this object contains values which I cannot get in the Servlets. Alternative would be a global static variable but I wonder if this is the way to go...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Embedded Jetty is so wonderful here.

You have a few common options:

1. Direct instantiation of the servlet, use constructors or setters, then hand it off to Jetty via the `ServletHolder` (can be any value or object type)
2. Add it to the `ServletContext` in your main, and then access it via the `ServletContext` in your application (can be any value or object type).

Examples:

```java
package jetty;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;

public class ObjectPassingExample
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server(8080);

        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
        context.setContextPath("/");

        // Option 1: Direct servlet instantiation and ServletHolder
        HelloServlet hello = new HelloServlet("everyone");
        ServletHolder helloHolder = new ServletHolder(hello);
        context.addServlet(helloHolder, "/hello/*");

        // Option 2: Using ServletContext attribute
        context.setAttribute("my.greeting", "you");
        context.addServlet(GreetingServlet.class, "/greetings/*");

        server.setHandler(context);
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }

    public static class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet
    {
        private final String hello;

        public HelloServlet(String greeting)
        {
            this.hello = greeting;
        }

        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
        {
            resp.setContentType("text/plain");
            resp.getWriter().println("Hello " + this.hello);
        }
    }

    public static class GreetingServlet extends HttpServlet
    {
        private String greeting;

        @Override
        public void init() throws ServletException
        {
            this.greeting = (String) getServletContext().getAttribute("my.greeting");
        }

        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
        {
            resp.setContentType("text/plain");
            resp.getWriter().println("Greetings to " + this.greeting);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The overridden `init` method works perfectly! Thanks.

Comment: What if I am using a WebAppProvider?  How can I get the ServletContext in the main method?

Comment: @Ben that's out of scope of this question specifically.  Please ask a new question (I'll answer it if I see it)

Answer (score 1):

## Singleton

You want to pass the same single instance to each servlet?

Use the [Singleton pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) to create a single instance that is available globally.

The simplest fool-proof way to do that in Java is through an [`Enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html). See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). Also see [this article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=3) and the book *Effective Java: Programming Language Guide, Second Edition* (ISBN 978-0-321-35668-0, 2008) by [Dr. Joshua Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch).

So no need to pass an object. Each servlet can access the same single instance through the enum.

## Per web app

If you want to do some work when your web app is first launching but before any servlet in that web app has handled any request, write a class that implements the [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) interface.

Mark your class with the [`@WebListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html) annotation to have your web container automatically instantiate and invoke.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you investigate Google's solution to this problem... namely: dependency injection with [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice).  They have a special [servlet package](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Servlets) that deals with servlets specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation but needed to share a singleton with a servlet deployed via war with hot (re)deploy in a Jetty container. The accepted answer wasn't quite what I needed in my case since the servlet has a lifecycle and context managed by a deployer.

I ended up with a brute-force approach, adding the object to the `server` context, which persists for the life of the container, and then fetching the object from within the servlet(s). This required loading the class of the object in a parent (system) classloader so that the war webapp doesn't load its own version of the class into its own classloader, which would cause a cast exception as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826319/classcastexception-when-casting-to-the-same-class).

**Embedded Jetty server code:**

```
    Server server = new Server(8090);

    // Add all classes related to the object(s) you want to share here.
    WebAppContext.addSystemClasses(server, "my.package.MyFineClass", ...);

    // Handler config
    ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
    HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();
    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { contexts });
    server.setHandler(handlers);

    // Deployer config (hot deploy)
    DeploymentManager deployer = new DeploymentManager();
    DebugListener debug = new DebugListener(System.err,true,true,true);
    server.addBean(debug);
    deployer.addLifeCycleBinding(new DebugListenerBinding(debug));
    deployer.setContexts(contexts);
    deployer.setContextAttribute(
            "org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern",
            ".*/[^/]*servlet-api-[^/]*\\.jar$|.*/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-.*\\.jar$|.*/[^/]*taglibs.*\\.jar$");

    WebAppProvider webapp_provider = new WebAppProvider();
    webapp_provider.setMonitoredDirName("/.../webapps");
    webapp_provider.setScanInterval(1);
    webapp_provider.setExtractWars(true);
    webapp_provider.setConfigurationManager(new PropertiesConfigurationManager());

    deployer.addAppProvider(webapp_provider);
    server.addBean(deployer);

    // Other config...

    // Tuck any objects/data you want into the root server object.
    server.setAttribute("my.package.MyFineClass", myFineSingleton);

    server.start();
    server.join();
```

**Example servlet:**

```
public class MyFineServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    MyFineClass myFineSingleton;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException
    {
        // Sneak access to the root server object (non-portable).
        // Not possible to cast this to `Server` because of classloader restrictions in Jetty.
        Object server = request.getAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server");

        // Because we cannot cast to `Server`, use reflection to access the object we tucked away there.
        try {
            myFineSingleton = (MyFineClass) server.getClass().getMethod("getAttribute", String.class).invoke(server, "my.package.MyFineClass");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new ServletException("Unable to reflect MyFineClass instance via Jetty Server", ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello from MyFineServlet</h1>");
        response.getWriter().println("Here's: " + myFineSingleton.toString());
    }
}
```

My build file for the servlet (sbt) placed the `my.package.MyFineClass` dependency into the "provided" scope so it wouldn't get packaged into the war as it will already be loaded into the Jetty server.

Comment: For me, the servlet context does not have an attribute for "org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server", when in the init method of the servlet.  Do you have to do something special to get that?

Comment: @Ben, are you using jetty or another container? As mentioned, this is non-portable to other servlet containers, at least as-is, you'll need to use the exact fully-qualified class name of the `Server` class that your container implements, and is possible this might change for Jetty as well in different versions.